# dynamic switch between audio (applications) source

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio, rhythmbox, youtube

Formuling a question was quite hard :)
I would like to know if there is a way to force the soundoutput to play the last audio stream started, reduce the volume of the actual audio source and when the playback is finished, increase the volume of the first source playing.
Concretly:

- I'm listening music with rhythmbox
- I'm surfing on the web on chrome/Moz and start a youtube video
- The audio playback of rhytmbox stop (or volume to 0)
- The audio playback of Youtube (Chrome/Moz) start
- When the video is finished, the playback of rhythmbox start again.

I'm listening music 99% of the time I'm on my computer and I feel stupid to have to stop/start everytime I want to watch a video. And I'm making this 10000 times a day I was wondering if there is any existing solution for this.
Hope I'm understandable :)
Gruß,
H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Earcandy](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/earcandy) [image: Install earcandy]

This application claims to be able to exactly do what you need:

> - All volume adjustments are fades
> - Fade out music/video players on skype call
> - Fade to music player with focus when more than one
> - **Fade out music player when video playing**
> - Push sound to USB headsets on plugin
> - Switch existing to USB mic on input
> - Categories to assign to clients
> - Sniffs desktop files to guess application category ... music/video/VoIP
> - Simplified pref UI for creating rules
> - Volume sniffing to fix youtube video issue
> - PID matching
> - Reset volumes for streams on exit (so streams dont get stuck at a low level)
> - Updated simplified (yes even more) UI to include volume meters
> - Ability to manage multiple devices
>
> **Source:** [Project on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/earcandy)

There still are some bugs, and it may not work stable on some systems. However it may be worth to try out.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! this is exactly what i was searching for! 
unfortunatelly they don't support 13.04. I will have to wait a bit. 
Still why such thing is not implemented in the distro. I don't think that I'm the ony one needing (badly) such function.
Thanks again!
*edit: found a V0.9 .deb and tried it. it doesn't work :(